# Create video movie from dynamic content

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, actionscript

I have an application (actionscript) that displayes a slideshow from dynamic content written in xml. The slideshow runs in flashplayer. Now i have been asked to display the content as a video file format. Is it possible to do such a thing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking, can I show video in my slideshow?  or are you asking if you can record the slideshow and display it as a video?

Comment: My question is can you create a video from dynamic data. Something like http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page but written in actionscript

Comment: I think we've found the secret behind web driver torso http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsLiV4WJfkTEHH0b9PmRklw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer Your Question,

If I understand you correctly, and you want to create either timeline or scripted animation, and have as3 record what appears, then the answer is Yes.

Below is a great example:
http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/

Really, all you have to do is to make all your actions and child animations happen inside a single Sprite or MovieClip, and then after every frame, copy the pixels from that object as it appears for that frame, and store those pixel in a ByteArray or even a Vector array of BitmapData.

That being said, once you have the data you will need to learn about encoding; yet, there are a ton of libraries out there that can help you avoid having learn a file spec and make an encoder from scratch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. Do you think this solution can handle creating 90 seconds of a movie?

Comment: 90s shouldn't be an any kind of issue; yet, it does depend on the vastness of the rect you are capturing, the resources available, and your process of encoding.